# Filter multiple items within an array reactively before publishing via publish composite

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I quite like using `publish-composite` for a very complex publication I have. However, I have a situation where I need to filter an array. The array must be filtered to only roles the current user and the published user both belong to. Example document:

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  guilds: [
    { slug: 'ascension' },
    { slug: 'warlords-of-draenor' },
    { slug: 'archers-anonymous' }
  ]
}
```

If I was to publish the player normally, I could do something like the following for the cursor.

```
Meteor.publish('player', function (id) {
  check(id, String);

  const allRoles = Roles.getAllRoles().map(role => role.name);
  const handle = Meteor.users.find(id).observe({
    added: doc => {
      doc.guilds = doc.guilds.filter(guild => Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, allRoles, guild.slug));
      this.added('users', doc._id, doc);
    }
  });
  this.ready();
  this.onStop(() => handle.stop());
});
```

The problem is, I do not think that I can integrate this with publish composite *because it will not return a cursor* to be passed to the children.

Is there a solution where I can alter the document before passing it to the children?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime my query/filter option complicated, I often insert it into the temp-collection, then query and publish from it.
In your case, I think you can try insert result to temp-collection like guild-temp.

```
Meteor.publish('player', function (id) {
   check(id, String);

   const allRoles = Roles.getAllRoles().map(role => role.name);
   const handle = Meteor.users.find(id).observe({
       added: doc => {
       doc.guilds = doc.guilds.filter(guild => Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, allRoles, guild.slug));
       this.added('users', doc._id, doc);
   }
   //insert handle result to temp-collection
   TempCollection.insert(handle...);
   return TempCollection.find(condition)...
   this.ready();
   this.onStop(() => handle.stop());
```

});